# how get First Access date on moodle?

Tags: moodle

i use a plugin : **[Course completion overview](https://moodle.org/plugins/report_completionoverview)**
but i need one more column with the date of first access of users,
what sql i need?

Comment: You mean the first login on Moodle or first access to the course?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the user first access to Moodle, you have to edit the index.php file in the plugin folder and edit this MySQL request:

```
$compdatacoursesql = "SELECT u.id AS userid, c.id as courseid,
[...]
u.email,
[...]
```

by adding:

```
u.firstaccess AS userfirstaccess,
```

So it will be:

```
$compdatacoursesql = "SELECT u.id AS userid, c.id as courseid,
[...]
u.email,
u.firstaccess AS userfirstaccess, 
[...]
```

Then in the foreach add

```
$a[] = ($row->userfirstaccess? date('jS F Y H:i:s', ($row->userfirstaccess)) : 'Never connected');
```

PHP date() function make the date human readable

Comment: thanks ! you are god ! jeje , and only for curiosity, the sql of last access to modle, can be:
u.lastaccess AS userlastaccess , ? thanks

Comment: Yes it works also for lastaccees, you can find the table schema on Moodle docs: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Database_schema_introduction#Users_and_their_profiles